# UploadField 'From files' not opening into folder name that has been set in the CMS

Tags: silverstripe

When in the CMS, when clicking the `From Files` option when uploading an image, I want the folder to open into the folder that has been specified.

E.g with my example below I want it to load into the `HeaderImages` folder. Instead it is showing all uploaded images and not actually going to that folder.

I thought by setting the folder name it would open into that folder. (I am sure it has done this in previous versions).

```
$fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
    UploadField::create('HeaderImage')->setFolderName('HeaderImages')
));
```

I am using SilverStripe 3.3.2.

How do I set the default folder for when the `From Files` button is pressed on an `UploadField`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3.3 we can call [`setDisplayFolderName`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-UploadField.html#_setDisplayFolderName) to define the default folder for when `From Files` is pressed on an `UploadField`:

```
$fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
    UploadField::create('HeaderImage')
        ->setFolderName('HeaderImages')
        ->setDisplayFolderName('HeaderImages')
));
```

Comment: Legend! Thank you :)